# Random Array problems

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I've been having problem in my code in this part:

```
Random rand = new Random();
string[] MyRandomArray = choices.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
string[] newArray = new string[4];

int num = 0;

for (num = 0; num < 3; num++)
{
    newArray[num] = MyRandomArray[num];
}

newArray[num] = "1";

string[] finalArray = newArray.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
this.radioButton1.Text = newArray[0];
this.radioButton2.Text = newArray[1];
this.radioButton3.Text = newArray[2];
this.radioButton4.Text = newArray[3];
```

What I'm trying to do is to get different places of array in newArray in radio button 1, 2, 3 and 4. However, I've been having a problem in the last array that I've assigned. It is not included in the shuffle, so the only random value I get is in radio buttons 1, 2, and 3. Radio button 4 stays the same whenever I try to restart the program.

Comment: Change your `for` loop to `for (num = 0; num <= 3; num++)` =)

Comment: thanks for the fast response andre, i cant do that because i want to assign newArray[num] = "1"

Comment: But, at that point, `num` is 2. You never set a value to `newArray[3]`!

Comment: i assign num to 0, then i transfer 3 strings to newArray, and assign the last element of new array to 1

Comment: Again: at that point, `num` is 2. You must assign like `num+1` to reach the last (4th) element.

Comment: ohhh ya!!! i forgot to tell that i tried adding 1 awhile ago cause i get this error "Index was outside the bounds of the array". thats why i change 4 to 3

Comment: Or--- Mary could change the `for` loop to `for( num = 0 ; num < 4 ; num++ )`. Either this or as Andre Alili suggested will work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

**A word on random sampling and potential problems:**

The [Random Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) has some limitations in its ability to generate unique sequences of random numbers see the Remarks section of the documentation:

1. Specifically, because the default constructor for Random initializes
   with a seed based on the system clock, you can get repeated
   sequences when the initialization of a Random instance is repeated
   very quickly. The Remarks section referenced previously includes
   code that demonstrates this problem.
2. Calls to the methods of a Random class instance are not guaranteed
   to be thread safe. So using a single instance of Random to avoid the
   seeding problem can run into other threading issues.

Using the [Guid.NewGuid Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) to sample a set will give better results for producing random ordering as it will not repeat sequences if called in rapid succession. However, it does come with some caveats:

1. While it does do well in a Chi-square test as a random **selector**,
   it is not suitable for cryptographic purposes, nor is it a direct
   substitute for an actual random number generator.
2. As long as the GUID produced by NewGuid is a version 4 GUID, the
   GUID does contain random content; however, this could possibly
   change in the future. Microsoft has not made any statements that
   guarantee GUIDs will contain random content, only that they will be
   unique with an extremely low probability of collision.

Here's what using NewGuid looks like:

```
string[] myRandomArray = choices.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3).ToArray();
```

Using the [RNGCryptoServiceProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) is the best solution for producing a reliable random sampling. It is both thread safe and does not suffer from the seeding problems that the Random Class has. It does, however, require more code to implement.

```
// TODO: Add code to demonstrate using RNGCryptoServiceProvider
```

You can use take rather than a For loop since you are already using LINQ:

```
// Get 3 random choices in a List.
List<string> myChoices = choices.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3).ToList();

// Add the correct answer.
myChoices.Add(theAnswer);

// Randomize the resulting set of 4 choices into an Array.
string[] myRandomizedChoices = myChoices.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();

this.radioButton1.Text = myRandomizedChoices[0];
this.radioButton2.Text = myRandomizedChoices[1];
this.radioButton3.Text = myRandomizedChoices[2];
this.radioButton4.Text = myRandomizedChoices[3];
```

Comment: i see, so this code will take 4 from choices array? can i assign this to another array cause i only want to take 3 and the 4th element would be an assign string

Comment: thanks for the help, seems i got solve my problem ussing if else and random number

Comment: @MaryGraceIsananViaje [Guids are not random](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/04/30/guid-guide-part-two.aspx) and shouldn't be used as random number generators.  This code is inherently broken and should *not* be used as it cannot be relied on to work, even if it *may* work in some situations.

Comment: `Random` is good enough for practical purposes - not truly random, but enough for non-cryptographic purposes. The problems you're talking about occur when you create a new instance of the `Random` class with each iteration, but that's not happening in the question.

Comment: @Servy Actually, you are not correct. Just because Guids can be monotonically increasing does not mean they will be. The link you provided specifically discusses version 1 Guids. The Guids generated by `Guid.NewGuid()` in .NET and `NEWID()` in SQL are version 4 Guids and sufficiently random for ordering a sample set. There is a monotonically increasing GUID in SQL using the `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` function, but it is limited to the default value for a column only.

Comment: @JamieSee And how do you know that you're always going to get version 4 guids with this code (hint, you don't)?  You could get version 4 guids, you could get version 1 guids, or if you're still running this code 5 years from now you could be using version 8 guids that do who knows what.  The point is, at the end of the day, a GUID doesn't represent a random number.  It might, possibly, in some circumstances be implemented using random numbers, but you cannot rely on that.  You should use a GUID when you need a *unique* number, not a random number.  This is all discussed in that article series.

Comment: @Servy Where you are correct is that what is generated by Guid.NewGuid is not a direct substitute for a random number generator, nor is it suitable for cryptographic puproses. It does well enough as a simple input for pseudo-random ordering of a non-cryptographic sample. You need to see part three for version 4 GUIDs (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/05/07/guid-guide-part-three.aspx). What using Guid.NewGuid() is, is an easy way to ensure that if the code is wrapped in a method and called repeatedly, rapidly, you won't get the exact same sequence because of a seed problem.

Comment: @Servy If there's a concern that it may change to a non-random sequence in the future (rather unlikely since it's been stable for years now, but possible) checking the GUID version identifier and throwing an exception if it's not 4 would be easy.

Comment: @JamieSee So did you just ignore my last comment, or half of the things that Eric said in his post?  I repeat the question I asked you before, "How do you know that you're going to get type 4 GUID generation using this code?"  Next, see the first line of Eric's summary: "GUIDs are guaranteed to be unique but not guaranteed to be random. **Do not use them as random numbers.**"  As well as several of the others that are relevant here.  The code in the OP uses `Random` properly, and doesn't have seeding problems.  When using GUIDs, it is actually possible to get the same sequence back.

Comment: @JamieSee Seriously; checking the guid type and throwing.  So now you're going to crash your entire application because they're not using the GUID generation algorithm that you think they should be.  And even then, how is that easier than just using **the right tool for the job** and actually using a class that is *designed* to generate random numbers.  It takes one small extra line of code to do; it's not like it's hard.

Comment: @Servy The use of new Random() does have a seed problem when repeated rapidly because of the time dependency of the default seed mechanism. Also, the Guid is not being used as a Random number. It's being used as a key to sample a sequence which is not necessarily the same thing. The fact is that in actual practice GUIDs are sufficiently random for that specific purpose. There is more than one way to address the question, and I'll update the answer soon with multiple ways to accomplish this and the caveats of each as some of your points are valid. In the meantime, please wait for the revision.

Comment: @JamieSee The use of `Random` can be used improperly, *but it's not being used improperly here*.  It's a matter of scoping the random object at the appropriate level, which is handled appropriately here.  Were it not, then the fix would be to scope it appropriately, not to use something that doesn't represent a random number.  Yes, you *are* using the GUID as a random number.  It's also being used in a projection, but the point is that you're projecting the value to a random number.  And no, a GUID cannot be relied on to be that.  If you get a type 1 GUID you can get the same sequence back.

Comment: @Servy While what you say is true as the code currently stands, the most likely use for this code is to wrap it in a method and call the method -- repeatedly. If that is the case, Random will exhibit the problem that I call out. Also, due to thread safety and seed issues with Random, the fix is not necessarily as simple as rescoping the use of Random. See this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/995e4dc7-60a7-4823-91ec-a4f87efc67f9/is-random-class-truly-thread-safe and the links it references.

Comment: @Servy Regarding the use of NewGuid, NewGuid will NEVER yield a version 1 value in the current iterations of the .NET Framework. (Probably not in future ones either. It is a valid point that that is not guaranteed, however, which is why I made that a very clear caveat when I posted the revised answer.) Yes, people will do this as it's a quite common carry over from SQL programming where people do the same thing. Yes, people need to understand how it could end up broken too. It also means mentioning it and its consequences is useful.

Comment: @Servy RNGCryptoServiceProvider is really the best, safest answer, but i only have so much time per day I can stackoverflow. Code will come later when I have time.